# CSS link in html

Tags: hyperlink

I'm linking to a css file in html but it doesn't seem to apply.

/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

html is complaining on the second < as if it wouldn't be closed and is marked red. Anyone who know's anything about this issue?

Comment: href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css"

Answer (score 0):

The CSS link in an HTML page you have to do it like this
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />` provided that the HTML and CSS file are in the same folder

Comment: Yes they are in the same folder